# How to delete a base map in GRASS?

Tags: raster, grass-gis

I'm trying to delete a map that I used as a mask before, but I cannot delete it using g.remove. It displays this:

g.remove rast=raster_Mnorzagaray@PERMANENT
[raster_Mnorzagaray@PERMANENT@PERMANENT] is a base map. Remove reclassed map first: MASK@PERMANENT

Comment: What's happening if you only write *g.remove rast=raster_Mnorzagaray* ?

Comment: when i write that, `g.remove rast=raster_Mnorzagaray                                                
[raster_Mnorzagaray@PERMANENT] is a base map. Remove reclassed map first: MASK@PERMANENT` is displayed. I used raster_Mnorzagaray previously as a mask and Im trying to remove it because i will use the same name for another map

Comment: you should probably remove the mask before, with the command *r.mask -r* then *g.remove rast=raster_Mnorzagaray*

Comment: I did that but it still produced the same error. raster_Mnorzagaray is not anymore in the list of raster maps but I cannot use the same name to create another map with the same name.

Comment: Same here. Maybe we need to extend/alter the WARNING message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is another map that uses that one as base map, it maybe a RGB composition or something like it. If you don't find what it is, just delete the map from the grassdata directory, you will find it in `cell`, `cell_misc` and `cellhd` folders in `grassdata\location\mapset\`.

Comment: How safe is that though?

Comment: It won't crash the program, but certainly the composition will not work anymore.

Comment: Yes, sort of the latter I was referring to.

Answer (score 3):

The command `[g.remove][1]` with flag `-b` can be used to remove base maps.

Comment: Using native grass modules is safer, in any case. Also, one can force the removal of _any_ map by issuing the _force_ flag, i.e.: `g.remove rast=raster_Mnorzagaray -f`.

Comment: I agree with @Nikos, the right way is to use the force flag

Comment: Just a note, g.mremove ceased existing in GRASS ver. 7.x. It's capacilities are all present in `g.remove`.

Comment: Can someone please edit `[g.remove][1]` to [`g.remove`][1] so the link "[1]: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/g.remove.html" works?